# .htaccess to redirect all domain URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect example.com and example.com/ALL aswell as example.com/ALL/ALL, example.com/ALL/ALL/ALL etc. to example.com/offline.html, temporary. How can I do this through .htaccess ?

ALL = whatever you type
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Redirect 302 / http://example.com/offline.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use .htaccess for this.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html#when

I'd recommend a proxy server.

Shovels for digging, hoes for sowing.

Answer (score 0):

you just need create an HTML file called App_offline.htm then copy this file to the root of your web application

for more details have a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f735abw9(VS.85).aspx